# Append text and image in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

For Append Text

```
private void AddText(string text)
{
    string[] str = text.Split(new string[] { ";" },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if (str.Length == 2)
    {
        richTextBox1.DeselectAll();
        richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
        richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + str[0] + ";");
        richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Regular);
        richTextBox1.AppendText(str[1]);
    }
}
```

For Append Image

```
Image image = Image.FromFile("Logo.jpg");

// Put the image on the clipboard
Clipboard.SetImage(image);

//// Paste it into the rich tetx box.
richTextBox1.Paste();
```

I do not know how can create RichTextBox like This image? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 2 rows x 3 columns table and add the elements to the corresponding cells. If you don't want its borders to appear use the `\brdrcf1` tag with white color from the color table.
More about rtf tables:
[Using Tables in RTF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349827/using-tables-in-rtf/13321729#13321729)