# Creating tables at run time?

Tags: c#, rtf

C# WinForms:

If I want to create tables at run time for a rich text box, should I programmaticly create the RTF specification syntax of a table and pass it to its rtf text? Is there any better way?

Comment: Does it have to be a rich text box? Can you use a [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx)?

Comment: hmm good idea.. the goal at the end is to be able to insert it into a text editor , the report page that we print.. and that's a "TX Text Control" .. ( this to be exact http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/products/activex/overview/ ),  So do you think later I can somehow cretae RTF from DataGrid? or somehow insert it into that editor?

Comment: Same question was asked here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/bf3169f9-dec8-4045-9b12-51b0d2230087 please see the answers hope they help you

Comment: You can take a look at this, it's not that difficult:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/13321729/1543816