# Automatic generation of RTF table

Tags: unix, rtf

I need to export some information that exist in a Linux text file into Windows Word file containing a few tables.

Is there a ready made tool that will create a nice RTF table in Linux? 
The input can be CSV, or maybe some other simple table format.

I've tried Googling, but most results are the vice verse (create simple txt from RTF).

I've tried to write something myself, (according to [Using Tables in RTF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349827/using-tables-in-rtf))
but encountered some problems, and thought that maybe there is no need to re-invent the wheel...

Thanks
:)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the table in html and convert it to rtf [using unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/). It requires  a recent LibreOffice or OpenOffice with UNO bindings.

Comment: Using HTML as source input makes sense, and unoconv seems to be an interesting project. However, it cannot help me. It's a Corporate machine, without office suite installed :(