# Spacing in String.Format()

Tags: c#, wpf

I want fixed spacing between words in a string similar to what you have in a datagrid.

I tried:

```
string item = String.Format("{0,-9}{1,-42}{2,-24}{3,0}", ++i, itemName, itemQuantity, totalItemPrice.ToString("#,##0.00") + System.Environment.NewLine);
```

But since the itemName length is varaible itemQuantity and totalItemPrice do not maintain their positions and get pushed forward.

The string is subsequently assigned to a RichTextBox.

Comment: `{0,-9}` Are you sure you can do that with `String.Format`?

Comment: Well i can't use "\t" since I get either too much or too little indentation. {0,-9) adds padding to the right

Comment: @SonerGönül, it aligns on the left `:)`

Comment: @491243 Interesting, I didn't know that.

Comment: I want the words left aligned

Comment: Are you using a monospaced (fixed-pitch) font?

Comment: Maybe PadLeft() or PadRight() can help you

Comment: @MatthewWatson No. Do you think that could be causing the problem?

Comment: @kr13 You will not be able to line things up with a proportional font using string.Format() unless you are only displaying digits (which all have the same width even in a proportional font). Since you are using RTF, you may be able to use a table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349827/using-tables-in-rtf

Comment: Matthew Watson is right - the 'item' strings _are_ lined up, it is the display which is wrong. Use a mono-spaced font (e.g. Courier) or table, as recommended.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks for the help. Can you add your comment as  an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string.Format() to line things up if you are using a monospaced (fixed-pitch) font.

However, you will not be able to line things up with a proportional font using string.Format() unless you are only displaying digits (which all have the same width even in a proportional font).

Since you are using RTF, you may be able to use a table if you need to use a proportional font.

See here for some more information: [Using Tables in RTF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349827/using-tables-in-rtf)

But the easiest solution is just to use a monospaced font, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

I have just modified the way you have used the values and I can get the data displayed as data grid.

```
 string itemName = "phone";

 int itemQuantity = 5, totalItemPrice=50;

 string item = String.Format("{0,-2}{1,-10}{2,-5}{3,-5}", ++i, itemName, itemQuantity, totalItemPrice.ToString("#,##0.00")+System.Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Is it the correct way as you want to do or else some specific way you want to display your data?

Comment: I does not seem to work for me. Can you tell me what font you used? Also did you get the result displayed in a richtextbox?

Comment: Actually you want which type of font?

Comment: Thanks for your help Jigna but the problem is solved. I had to use a monospace font