# RTF document headers

Tags: rtf

I need to write a line of RTF that will create a header in APA style. That is, the title is to be left-flushed and the page number right-flush. How do I split that up? This, for example, gives me everything right-flushed:

```
{\header \pard\qr THE TITLE \chpgn \par}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with hand-writing RTF, but from [the specification](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading40) it looks like you can do the following:

1. Create a table row with two cells (paragraphs)
2. Make the first cell left-aligned, this will be contain the title
3. Make the second cell right-aligned, this will contain the page number

You may also find this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8349827/477563) about RTF tables of some use.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a tab stop, at the far right of the page, and right align that tab stop.

```
{\header \pard\tx9972\tqr THE TITLE \tab\chpgn \par}
```

- `\tx9972` says to set the position of the tab stop to 9972 twips.
- `\tqr` says tab stop right aligned
- `\tab` insert a tab